# Why are my items in the list have so much space between?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list, that view some items, but in the list there is between the rows so much place.

Here are the card_item_std.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="Id" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:text="Name" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my activity_main.xml is only the full page defined and the list in the bottom as recycleview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="SQLite Demo"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:hint="Enter Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:hint="Enter Email" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="View"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a part, where I need to reduce the padding of the list items?

On the picture you can see that between the rows are so much space.

[image]

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` calculates the entire screen height so you get each item screen height size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to change to wrap_content

Comment: Lately, I see a lot of people answering in a comment instead of officially posting an answer; why is that?

Comment: @rtsketo I usually do it when I can see that the question should probably be closed as a duplicate but I just want to quickly help the person rather than take time to search for the similar question that has decent answers on it. This question fits that situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this line `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` as follow

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cardview_shadow_end_color"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1">
    
...    

/>
```